# What causes fibromyalgia to flare up even though medicine is used?

Tags: fibromyalgia

My mother has fibromyalgia and her condition flared up suddenly without any warning. She is taking prescription pills for the condition. I would like to know if anybody can help me to find out what would cause this flare-up and also where I can find good resources about this condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uptodate](http://www.uptodate.com/contents/treatment-of-fibromyalgia-in-adults-not-responsive-to-initial-therapies?source=outline_link&view=text&anchor=H22299532#H22299532) discusses secondary failure after an initial response to drug therapy.

> FACTORS LIMITING TREATMENT EFFICACY — Several factors may limit the degree of benefit achieved with prescribed medications or other interventions, including nonadherence to treatment interventions or comorbidities that cause peripheral pain and that require additional interventions to those used for treatment of the fibromyalgia.

However, in general, the effect of medication is modest in fibromyalgia, and should only be part of a multidisciplinary treatment program which includes exercise, cognitive based therapies, and sleep hygiene.